# How do I approach on proving the following fact - 1. Every path is Bipartite?

Tags: graph-theory

I am new to Graph Theory. I have sufficient background in Linear Algebra. I found the question in the first exercise of 'Graph Theory' by Bondy and Murty.

Comment: Given what "bipartite" means there is no choice in how to form the partition.  Odd and even numbered positions on the path are the two parts of the partition.

Comment: Thanks. looks obvious now. should have checked all combinations of vertices.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A path is acyclic. A graph is bipartite if and only if it contains no cycles of odd length. Therefore, a path is bipartite. QED.

Comment: The characterization with cycles is unnecessary for a path, because there is an extremely simple description of what the two classes of vertices are.